# Does a HDMI splitter exist that will split hdmi into video and audio?

Tags: google-tv, hdmi

I'm trying to hook up a GoogleTV to an older Sony TV and the TV has an HDMI input but just below it are the familiar red and white RC jacks for audio. I remember trying to hook up my XBox and the audio not working and now I'm having the same issue with GoogleTV and I think it's because this was made before the audio was integrated into HDMI or something.

I look all though the TV setting and couldn't find a "use RCA jacks for audio option" and was wondering if anyone ran into this before and if maybe there is some sort of splitter I could buy.

Comment: The Sony doesn't have the yellow video jack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[4x2 True HDMI Matrix Switch w/ Analog Audio Output](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=101&cp_id=10110&cs_id=1011002&p_id=7112&seq=1&format=2)

or

[1 x 2 HDMI Splitter Distribution Amplifiier with Toslink Audio Output](http://www.octavainc.com/HDMI%20distribution%20amp_splitter%202%20port.html)

Comment: $200! That's 20% of buying a new 55 inch TV! Thanks though.

Comment: The first one is $59 and splits the audio and video as you requested.  You *may* be able to find something cheaper direct from China.

Answer (score -1):

I found that:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/5Ft-HDMI-Male-to-5RCA-5-RCA-Audio-Video-AV-Component-Cable-Gold-Plated-/390383800639?pt=US_Video_Cables_Adapters&hash=item5ae4b0113f

I'm still waiting for it but that can be good for you too!

Regards!

Comment: That seems very unlikely to help. As the item description points out, the cable just puts the digital HDMI signal on some RCA (phono) connectors. It doesn't transcode it into the analogue signal a receiver would be expecting on RCA inputs. I don't know of any A/V receiver that can understand a digital audio signal on RCA inputs.